# Tiled Image for background of DIV is making IE sllllowww when scrolling

Tags: css, internet-explorer, performance

Take a look at http://www.pmverge.com at the "We're in Bootstrap Mode" DIV on the right-hand side.  Having that background tile image is causing the IE browser (all versions) to drag when scrolling.  What can I do to keep that tiled style but not have it slow down IE.

```
background-image: url(http://blog.pmverge.com/assets/images/background.gif)
```

NOTES

1. The tile image is only a few pixels
   high and wide
2. Yes this is the Stackoverflow.com
   engine as I'm licensing it.
3. The background watermark image is
   not slowing the page down (though it has about 50k).

Comment: it scrolls just fine for me in both ie6 and 7, the ads are a bit weirdly placed though

Comment: Try giving the image a higher width and height.

Comment: I have no problems with it in IE, FF, or Chrome.

Comment: It's only in IE.  I've had this problem in the past and solved it by ditching background tiles for DIVed areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the size of the image and see if you experience speed improvement.

Comment: Good thought.  I will try that.

Comment: That was what it was.  IE has a problem with small image tiles.  I made it 64x64 and now it's fast.

Comment: Yes, I found that out years ago when I was overoptimizing my tiles to something like 2x2.